# Automatically declare user set variable without submitting

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a view where a user needs to set a variable, but I don't need to store the variable anywhere.
That variable needs to be used in the calculation. For example - user inputs 5 and it automatically declares as $z. Is there a way to do it?

For bigger example, we can take convertunits webpage km/h to m/s. As you type in km/h it automatically shows results for m/s without using submit button.

Expected result - user inputs 5 and it declares as a variable without submitting. I have gone thru a lot of the same question posts but none are the thing I need.

Comment: Use JavaScript and do it on the clientside, or send it to PHP through AJAX

Comment: Typically a conversion website can be done exclusively client-side in JavaScript. You can use the `input` or `keyup` event to detect when a change has been made to an input and then use the `input.value` method to get the input. If you want to do this in PHP then some kind of data submission must be made because PHP is running on a server and not at the same place where the user is inputting data.

Comment: @Qirel The Ajax advice is a bad one. A roundtrip to the server for every digit the user types?

Comment: Of course not, @Michel. But that you set the variable in JS, and after the user is done typing, send the query. It depends entirely on the flow of data, but since there's no code, we can't really give a precise answer, merely spitball ideas.